# Determine whether there exists a one-to-one character mapping from one string to another

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

**The task**

> Determine whether there exists a one-to-one character mapping from one
>   string s1 to another s2.
>
> For example, given s1 = abc and s2 = bcd, return true since we can map
>   a to b, b to c, and c to d.
>
> Given s1 = foo and s2 = bar, return false since the o cannot map to
>   two characters.

The task is ambiguous. Here are my interpretations of the task and the corresponding solution:

**Interpretation 1:**

For every letter in one string there exists exactly one in the other. (order and position of the corresponding letter are irrelevant)

**My solution**

```
const s1 = "foo";
const s2 = "bar";

const isMappable = (s1, s2) => {
  if (s1.length !== s2.length) { return false; }

  const createOrderedMap = str => Object.values([...str]
    .reduce((map, s) => {
      map[s] = map[s] ? map[s] + 1 : 1;
      return map;
  }, {})).sort();
  const o1 = createOrderedMap(s1);
  const o2 = createOrderedMap(s2);
  if (o1.length !== o2.length) { return false; }
  for (let i = 0, len = o1.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (o1[i] !== o2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

console.log(isMappable(s1, s2));
```

**Interpretation 2:**

For every letter in one string there exists exactly one in the other at the exact order and position of the corresponding letter.

**My solution**

```
const s1 = "aab";
const s2 = "cdc";
const isMappable = (s1, s2) => {
  if (s1.length !== s2.length) { return false; }

  const map1 = new Map();
  const map2 = new Map();

  return [...s1].every((s, i) => {
    if (!map1.has(s) && !map2.has(s2[i])) {
      map2.set(s2[i], s);
      map1.set(s, s2[i]);
    }
    return map1.get(s) === s2[i]  && map2.get(s2[i]) === s;
  });
};

console.log(isMapable(s1, s2));
```

Comment: Is there a mapping between `abbb` and `cdcd`?

Comment: @vpn You are right. Fixed.

Comment: returns true for `aab`,`xyx`; seems incorrect to me?  I read this problem as "*can string A be transformed to string B by substitution cipher?*"

Comment: a can be mapped to one x, the other a to the other x, and b can be mapped to y? @OhMyGoodness

Comment: you responded faster than I could edit, but I understand your reading of the problem.  Depends on what they meant by "mapping", I guess.

Comment: @OhMyGoodness I also get your point. This task may be indeed in a realm of encryption. And it would be more challenging to do it your way. I’ll try to solve the task the way you understood it

Comment: Updated @OhMyGoodness

Comment: update only checks one direction `isMapable("abc","ddd")` should be false (is many-to-one instead of one-to-one).  And mappable is spelled with 2 p's :)